# How capturing the accurate execution time in c#

Tags: c#

I try to capture the exact execution time of function

```
Stopwatch regularSW = new Stopwatch();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    regularSW.Start();
    //function();
    regularSW.Stop();

    Console.WriteLine("Measured time: " + regularSW.Elapsed);
}
```

I also tried with `DateTime` and `Process.GetCurrentProcess().TotalProcessorTime`
but each time I get a different value.

How i can get same value ?

Comment: What do you want to measure? The realtime? The time spent by the processor on this task?

Comment: You should run it a lot of times to get an accurate reading. (1000 for example).

Comment: Why do you expect the same value always? StopWatch is a high-resolution timer, if that's not desired use a less accurate way. What does `function();`? Maybe it's normal to get a slightly different execution time always (f.e. if it's a database query).

Comment: You cannot. These are different instruments with different accuracy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `StopWatch` you already use the most accurate way. But you are not re-starting it in the loop. It always starts at the value where it ended. You either have to create a new `StopWatch` or call [`StopWatch.Restart`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.restart%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of `Start`:

```
Stopwatch regularSW = new Stopwatch();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    regularSW.Restart();
    //function();
    regularSW.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("Measured time: " + regularSW.Elapsed);
}
```

That's the reason for the different values. If you now still get  different values, then the reason is that the method `function` really has different execution times  which is not that unlikely(f.e. if it's a database query).

---

Since this question seems to be largely theoretical(regarding your comments), consider following things if you want to measure time in .NET:

- compile and run in release mode, Any CPU (on an x64 machine) and optimizations **on**
- A tick is 0.0001 milliseconds, so don't overestimate your results
- They are different because you cannot control what other operations your system might need to perform in the background while your C# progam is running
- If you for example claim memory in the method because you fill a local list, then the garbage collector might attempt to reclaim garbage(memory)
- C# code is compiled Just In Time. The first time you go through a loop can therefore be hundreds or thousands of times more expensive than every subsequent time due to the cost of the jitter analyzing the code that the loop calls. If you are intending on measuring the "warm" cost of a loop then you need to run the loop once before you start timing it. If you are intending on measuring the average cost including the jit time then you need to decide how many times makes up a reasonable number of trials, so that the average works out correctly
- you are running your code in a multithreaded, multiprocessor environment where threads can be switched at will, and where the thread quantum (the amount of time the operating system will give another thread until yours might get a chance to run again) is about 16 milliseconds. 16 milliseconds is about fifty million processor cycles. Coming up with accurate timings of sub-millisecond operations can be quite difficult if the thread switch happens within one of the several million processor cycles that you are trying to measure. Take that into consideration.

The last two points were copied from [this answer of Eric Lippert](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10111919/284240) (worth reading).

Comment: I have already use regularSW.StartNew() but same result (different result each time).

The function can be empty
function f(){} 

And the result will be different each time with microsecond or nanosecond

Comment: @Omega: So you are comparing ticks on each run and sometimes you get 0, 1 or 2? Why do you care about? Have you compiled in release mode? It's normal that the execution time is not equal (regarding ticks) every time. [Windows is not a real-time operating system](http://superuser.com/questions/406819/what-does-windows-is-not-a-real-time-operating-system-mean)

Comment: not just 0 1 or 2 but like 132.9057 133.0829 131.1492 ....
And yes In release mode.
And i need the same value if it's the same code with the same values

Comment: @Omega: then the function is not empty, what are you doing there? But don't expect the same execution time. If you for example claim memory in the method because you fill a local list, then the  garbage collector attempts to reclaim garbage(memory) eventually. So is this just a theoretical question or do you really need to rely on the same execution time. Then windows is not the right OS and C# not the right language.

Comment: Same result also for empty function or just basic function like:
- function f(){} or function f(){int a = 5}

Comment: If i use your loop and an empty method i get these result, so the execution time is nearly zero: `Measured time: 00:00:00.0000013
Measured time: 00:00:00.0000004
Measured time: 00:00:00
Measured time: 00:00:00.0000004
Measured time: 00:00:00
Measured time: 00:00:00
Measured time: 00:00:00
Measured time: 00:00:00
Measured time: 00:00:00
Measured time: 00:00:00.0000004`

Comment: But why we have 0000013 and 00.0000004 it's different why just same values for both of them ?

Comment: @Omega: a tick is 0.0001 milliseconds, so don't  overestimate
the values. First, have you  compiled and run in release mode, Any CPU (on an x64 machine)  and optimizations disabled which you should do? They are different  because you cannot control what other operations your system might need to perform in the background while your C# progam is running.

Comment: Second, you need to remember that C# code is compiled Just In Time. The first time you go through a loop can therefore be hundreds or thousands of times more expensive than every subsequent time due to the cost of the jitter analyzing the code that the loop calls. If you are intending on measuring the "warm" cost of a loop then you need to run the loop once before you start timing it. If you are intending on measuring the average cost including the jit time then you need to decide how many times makes up a reasonable number of trials, so that the average works out correctly.